# Issues when trying to remove the firebase reference

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, delete-row

I am having some issues while trying to delete one of the tableView row - in my case I was trying to delete the data from Firebase and then reload the table view.
See the function below:

```
 func deleteMeds() {
     Database.database().reference().child("Meds_Database").child("UsersID").child((Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid)!).child("User_Medications").observe(DataEventType.childRemoved, with: { (snapshot) in

        if let dictionary = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {

            let medication = Meds()

            medication.medName = (dictionary["Medication_Name"]) as! String
            medication.medDosage = (dictionary["Medication_Dosage"]) as! String
            medication.medEdit = (dictionary["Medication_Frequency"]) as! String
            medication.medAlarm = (dictionary["Medication_Reminder"]) as! String


            self.meds.remove(at: 0)

            DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

                self.tableView.reloadData()

            })


        }

        print(snapshot)

    }, withCancel: nil)

}
```

I think I am getting confused with the Firebase Syntax... Can somebody help me? The database is like this:
[image]

I am sure someone can help

Comment: i would suggest changing your firebase setup and use medication_name as the key instead of random generated, then whenever you need to delete x medication_name you can just reference that key and delete the value it contains

Comment: That may help... I'll try and update here

Comment: I am using a tableView and there will be a lot of cells with different names... But the user will slide to the left and delete that specific one. How can I create the function to remove the indexPath.row of the row selected?

Comment: Hmm coming from Android i would probably get the name of the row that would be deleted ( i assume that the user can see the name of the medication and then delete) - When this happens i will pass the name into the firebase reference child("User_Medications").child("medication_name").removeValue();

Not sure if the syntax is the same in swift :) --> Firebase is a key value database, so whenever you delete a key, all value under this key will be deleted

Answer (score 0):

You only need to delete the relavant object not always index 0 here

```
self.meds.remove(at: 0)
```

So replace it with

```
self.meds = self.meds.filter{ $0 != medication  }
```

and adopt the [Equatable](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol